# pip "pyrax" dependency with iron worker

Tags: python, pip, rackspace, iron.io, pyrax

I created a Python script to use Rackspace's API (Pyrax) to handle some image processing. It works perfect locally, but when I upload it to Iron.io worker, it builds but does not import.

I am using a Windows 8 pc, but my boss runs OS X and uploading the exact worker package, it works fine. So I'm thinking it's something with Windows 8 but I don't know how to check/fix.

I do apologize in advance if I ramble or do not explain things clearly enough but any help would be greatly appreciated.

My worker file looks like this:

**runtime "python"
exec "rackspace.py"
pip "pyrax"
full_remote_build true**

Then I simply **import pyrax** in my python file.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that it was a bad Ruby install. No idea why, but reinstalling it worked.

Comment: Glad you got this figured out. If you need more specifics, jump into our live chat http://get.iron.io/chat or hit us here on SO.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. If you run into any pyrax-specific issues, you can always post them on https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/issues

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know for sure what's happening without being able to see a traceback. Do you get anything like that which could be used to help figure out what's going on?